# Problem coomunication beetwen leshan client and iotAgent Fiware

Tags: iot, fiware, agent, fiware-orion, leshan

for a project i have to connect the Eclipse Leshan Client to a IoT Agent Server.
My problem is to read the device's mesurements with Postman or cUrl command.
The client after the configuration of the port (5683) look like it's connected to the server but i can't read the values of the dummy device.

I ask how i can connect the client to server. Which file have i to config for my work?.
Also i have set up an orion context broker on the port 1026. The listening port of the server is the port 5683.
I wish to use the devices registered in the client Leshan, but the data results EMPTY.

Fiware IoTAgent:
https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent;

Eclipse Leshan:
https://github.com/eclipse/leshan

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a workaround through that port in order to achieve your goal.

Best luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm trying but i can't understand how i can do it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).